# How do I delete data in my Firebase Realtime Database when using a ViewModel and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

So I use a `ViewModel` and `LiveData` for reading data from my Firebase Realtime Database.

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
class UsersViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
    private val USERS_REF: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
    private val liveData: FirebaseQueryLiveData = FirebaseQueryLiveData(USERS_REF)
    private val usersLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Users> = MediatorLiveData()

    init {
        usersLiveData.addSource(liveData, object : Observer<DataSnapshot> {
            override fun onChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                    usersLiveData.postValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(Users::class.java))
                } else {
                    usersLiveData.value = null
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @NonNull
    fun getUsersLiveData() : LiveData<Users> {
        return usersLiveData
    }
}
```

This is my `LiveData`:

```
class FirebaseQueryLiveData(ref: DatabaseReference) : LiveData<DataSnapshot>() {
    private val query: Query = ref
    private val listener: MyValueEventListener = MyValueEventListener()
    private var listenerRemovePending = false

    private val removeListener = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            query.removeEventListener(listener)
            listenerRemovePending = false
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        if (listenerRemovePending) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).removeCallbacks(removeListener)
        } else {
            query.addValueEventListener(listener)
        }
        listenerRemovePending = false
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(removeListener, 2000)
        query.removeEventListener(listener)
    }

    private inner class MyValueEventListener : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            value = snapshot
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do delete data from my database? I know I need to call `removeValue()` on a database reference, but how I should go about doing that? I have the database reference in my `ViewModel` so I would like to use that reference for deleting data.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't understand your question. I'm trying to figure out a way to delete the data as I have not included that code in my `ViewModel` or `LiveData`. I didn't say something wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As per MVVM, you can have a repository class with delete method which you can call from your viewmodel class. Then you can use livedata to be observed by the view for progress changes.

To delete:

```
val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("quotes").child(fieldKey)
databaseReference.removeValue()
```